# Different in results from query between query and join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Hi have this two tables:

#Customers

```
cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email
'1000000001', 'Village Toys', '200 Maple Lane', 'Detroit', 'MI', '44444', 'USA', 'John Smith', 'sales@villagetoys.com'
'1000000002', 'Kids Place', '333 South Lake Drive', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43333', 'USA', 'Michelle Green', NULL
'1000000003', 'Fun4All', '1 Sunny Place', 'Muncie', 'IN', '42222', 'USA', 'Jim Jones', 'jjones@fun4all.com'
'1000000004', 'Fun4All', '829 Riverside Drive', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', '88888', 'USA', 'Denise L. Stephens', 'dstephens@fun4all.com'
'1000000005', 'The Toy Store', '4545 53rd Street', 'Chicago', 'IL', '54545', 'USA', 'Kim Howard', NULL
```

#Orders

```
order_num, order_date, cust_id
'20005', '2012-05-01 00:00:00', '1000000001'
'20006', '2012-01-12 00:00:00', '1000000003'
'20007', '2012-01-30 00:00:00', '1000000004'
'20008', '2012-02-03 00:00:00', '1000000005'
'20009', '2012-02-08 00:00:00', '1000000001'
```

Now if I perform this query with subquery on a field calling it orders:

```
SELECT cust_name, 
       cust_state, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Orders 
        WHERE Orders.cust_id = Customers.cust_id) AS orders 
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY cust_name;
```

I get 'Kids Place' with orders 0:

```
cust_name, cust_state, orders
'Fun4All', 'IN', '1'
'Fun4All', 'AZ', '1'
'Kids Place', 'OH', '0'
'The Toy Store', 'IL', '1'
'Village Toys', 'MI', '2'
```

But if I use the join version:

```
SELECT c.cust_name, 
   c.cust_state,
    COUNT(*) orders
FROM Customers c 
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY o.cust_id
ORDER BY c.cust_name;
```

I don't get the 'Kids place' row:

```
cust_name, cust_state, orders
'Fun4All', 'IN', '1'
'Fun4All', 'AZ', '1'
'The Toy Store', 'IL', '1'
'Village Toys', 'MI', '2'
```

Why I get this behaviour?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, *chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.*

Comment: If you don't say why you expect what you expect, with justification per authoritative documentation, then you are just asking for us to rewrite it with a bespoke tutorial with no idea what your misconceptions are. That's not focused enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "INNER JOIN" will only return results that are found on both sides of the join (imagine the overlapping area in a venn diagram). Because there are no orders for Kids Place, there is no overlap in the join, and therefore no result returned.

If you want to use a join to make a similar query to your subquery, then you'd be looking at a LEFT JOIN. A left join will display all the results from the left side (Customers in your case), then try to join the corresponding results from the right (Orders in your case).

```
SELECT cust_name, 
       cust_state, 
       count(o.cust_id) as orders
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY cust_name, cust_state;
```

Example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a87b/5/0)

Comment: Yes but how? If I use LEFT JOIN in place of the INNER one I get en Error.

Comment: Thanks I want to study your solution to better understand the differences between the two queries.

Comment: Another thing: which is the better way to write it?

Comment: It depends :) generally speaking, the database you're using will do all sorts of optimizations behind the scenes for joins; however, a lot of people prefer subqueries due to improved readability - debugging a query with many joins can be a frustrating exercise. Looking at the execution plan for your queries will give you more insight into the performance of your queries and should help determine whether a join or subquery is better.

Comment: Forgive me another thing: why do if I do the query only grouping by cust_name I get an error and i need to use cust_state too?

Comment: It shouldn't be giving you an error, I get a result when I try on SQLFiddle. That being said, it's not a great result - it has one less row as it doesn't account for multiple states for Fun4All as we're grouping by name and there are 2 entries that share the same name. Really you should be grouping by c.cust_id rather than cust_name, cust_state since that's the unique identifier

Comment: Yeah I forgot to Group BY c.cust_id, I only used cust_id and it was ambigous.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` for the two to be equivalent:

```
SELECT c.cust_name, c.cust_state,
       COUNT(o.cust_id) as orders
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id
ORDER BY c.cust_name;
```

Also note that the `COUNT()` changed to count the number of matches.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I get an error: Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tysql.c.cust_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

Comment: It's wrong because the query doesn't group by c.cust_name, c.cust_state. The fields in the Select statement (expcept the ones in the aggregate functions) should be in the group by clause

Comment: Can you fix the example please?

Comment: @Hyruma92 . . . It (now) aggregated by `c.cust_id`.  There is every reason to think that this is the primary key and in that case it is fine to select other columns from the same table.